# Center message in android dialog box

Tags: java, android

I want the message text within my dialog box to be center aligned.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Create your own TextView object and then supply it to popup builder as View:

```
AlertDialog.Builder popupBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
TextView myMsg = new TextView(this);
myMsg.setText("Central");
myMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
popupBuilder.setView(myMsg);
```

You can control all other text parameters (style, color, size ...). To control margins you may programatically create LinearLayout, set LayoutParams, and then put TextView into it.

Comment: In case I want to add buttons or any other default components in order to get the default look of the dialog I need to do it by myself.
I liked more Chase answer.

Comment: I have to admit that I also like more the answer from Chase. This was the first approach that came to my mind, and I wanted to answer it quickly.

Answer (score 165):

Of course, you can always set the gravity of the original text view. This allows you to not have to worry about formatting and padding.

For example

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setMessage("Message");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

// Must call show() prior to fetching text view
TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Awesome trick. But it doesn't work for 'title' of AlertDialog !

Comment: I've not tested, but I'm sure you could do a similar thing for the Title by doing android.R.id.title. This works great for the message though.

Comment: Do you think this has a better perfomance? I know that this is impossiible to get from the user, just curious.

Comment: This is also a great solution as I can set a separate view to my dialog and still be able to control the attributes of the TextView. A custom TextView forces me to use it as the dialog's view.

Comment: For those who get null as a result. Read the answer carefully. _Must call show() prior to fetching text view_

Comment: Just a little FYI if anybody come across this,
**To change the text style of Positive,Negative and Neutral buttons the ids are `button1`,`button2` and `button3` respectively**

Answer (score 11):

Building off of Chase's answer, here's how to also center the title.  I think this is the easiest way.  Why android doesn't center by default or make it a simple constructor param is beyond me.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("My Title");
builder.setMessage("My message");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", listener);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

// Must call show() prior to fetching views
TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

TextView titleView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android"));
if (titleView != null) {
    titleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

we can use as like.

```
public static void showAlert(Activity activity, String message) {
  TextView title = new TextView(activity);

  title.setText("Your Title Here");
  title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
  title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  title.setTextSize(20);

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
  builder.setCustomTitle(title);
  builder.setMessage(message);
  builder.setCancelable(false);
  builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      dialog.cancel();
    }
  });

  AlertDialog alert = builder.show();
  TextView messageText = (TextView)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
  messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  messageText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code

```
public void Info(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Info Aplication");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.info_adp);
    builder.setMessage("Jakarta Hospital");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Exit", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Post a description above your code, so others can understand what you did

Comment: Post a description above your code, so others can understand what you did.

Comment: he is setting `android:gravity="center"`

Answer (score 3):

without using textview.
worked for me.

styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

Alertdialog

```
final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, 
R.style.CustomAlertDialog)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your TextView:

```
android:gravity = "center_vertical|center"
```