# how to align message in alertdialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i need to use an `AlertDialog` in my application which reads the contents form a text file. For that i had done as shown in http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/adding-eula-to-android-app/

It really helped me and is a nice tutorial for those who needs help...

But i need the text displayed inside that `AlertDialog` as central aligned..
how can i do this?

I had tried for customize dialog... But i cant get it worked..
i had checked many sites for references, but i failed to get a good tutorial.
Can anyone describe how to make a custom AlertDialog and how the message inside the dialog can be aligned?

I had written Styles.xml in values

```
<style name="RightJustifyTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
</style>

<style name="RightJustifyDialogWindowTitle" parent="@android:style/DialogWindowTitle">
     <item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
</style>

<style name="RightJustifyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RightJustifyTextView</item>       
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/RightJustifyDialogWindowTitle</item>       
</style>    

</resources>
```

but the style RightJustifyTextView and RightJustifyTheme shows error..

And i have updated my eula file with

```
public class RightJustifyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog {

        public RightJustifyAlertDialog(Context ctx) { 
              super(ctx, R.style.RightJustifyTheme); } }
```

i am not sure what i have done. but just tried to do something like http://s401.codeinspot.com/q/2052397

Step By Step desription will be very helpful for the students who are learning Android programming...
looking forward for good descriptive answers..

Comment: can you post code for custom AlertDialog?

Comment: [This should help you.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954130/message-text-in-android-dialog-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps:
http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/dialog-vs-alertdialog/

You could set the `TextView` with `id=@+id/textViewListName` to  `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`