# Show Long Message in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I am trying to display an lengthy message in Default AlertDialog with following code.

```
public static void showAlert(String message, Context con) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
    dialog.setTitle(message);
    dialog.setPositiveButton(" OK ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}
```

But when I pass long message Alert Dialog does not display full message. Can I align text of Dialog by center. I dont want to use Custom Dialog.

Comment: try dialog.setMessage(message) instead of setTitle ?

Comment: Thanks Urgo. It was a big Silly Mistake... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Urgo please post your comment as answer so that OP can accept it..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change

```
dialog.setTitle(message);
```

to

```
dialog.setMessage(message);
```

and if you want to center align the text, you'll have to create
a textview like in the following example:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
    dialog.setTitle(message);
    dialog.setPositiveButton(" OK ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    dialog.show();

// Must call show() prior to fetching text view
TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

taken from: [Center message in android dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954130/message-text-in-android-dialog-box)

Comment: And how to center align Text in Dialog

Answer (score 2):

try following code

```
public static void showAlert(String message, Context con) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setPositiveButton(" OK ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: And how to center align Text in Dialog

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());

builder1.setTitle("Login Alert");

TextView myMsg = new TextView(getParent());

myMsg.setText("You have not logged in to save the product.Do you want to login?");

myMsg.setTextSize(20);

myMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

builder1.setView(myMsg);
```