# How to center text in Alert Dialog Builder?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to center some text in a default Alert Dialog Builder
Here's my code so far, but it defaults to the left.

```
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Well done!")
                    .setMessage("Message centered????")

                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            })

                    .setIcon(R.drawable.img_ok)
                    .show();

        }
```

Comment: I have found `AlertDialog` to be hard to customize. I ended up creating a custom `Dialog` that contains a `View` exactly how I want.

Comment: I think you can find you answer here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954130/message-text-in-android-dialog-box
I hope it help you !

Comment: @koni Yes, I saw that link, quick answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of setting the message, use `AlertDialog.Builder.setView(View)` with a `View` with centred text

Answer (score 16):

This piece of code does the job by default, without providing your own custom view to the `AlertDialog.Builder` .

```
  AlertDialog dialog = builder.show(); //builder is your just created builder
    TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: setView is missing, dialod.setView(messageText); should be included before dialog.show();

Comment: FYI, the solution will only work if the "dialog.show()" is executed BEFORE the ".setGravity()", otherwise you'll get a NulPtr runtime exception

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
public void Info(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Info Aplikasi");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.info_adp);
    builder.setMessage("Jakarta Hospital");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Exit", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple method:

```
textView.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
alert.setView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Material Alert Dialog would be like this:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, com.google.android.material.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material3_MaterialAlertDialog_Centered)
    .setTitle("Titulo")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.people)
    .setMessage("un mensaje cualquiera");
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();    
((TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```