# Android Alert Message At Center not Working

Tags: android, alert

I followed [this](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/custom-alert-dialog-title-and-message.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954275/8039571)  to Show Alert dialog Message at Center.
Actually, It Should Be work Fine.

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
TextView myMsg = new TextView(this);
myMsg.setText("This is new Custom Alert \n And \n Welcome to android");
myMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
ad.setView(myMsg);
```

But its showing Error at Gravity like,
`error: cannot find symbol variable Gravity`

Can Any One Suggest me on this kind... it not even Compiling in New Android Studio.

Comment: **`WHERE IS YOUR CODE`**

Comment: please add your code

Comment: whats wrong with downvoters????????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class add this line with other imports like so

```
import android.view.Gravity
```

You can find more details on this official documentation page [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)

Comment: yes more 7 min to accept your answer.. Please Upvote.. my question

Answer (score 0):

```
setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).