# how to make center MaterialAlertDialogBuilder alignment title, message & button

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, material-components-android

how to make center alignment title, message & button

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
                .setTitle("Message")
                .setMessage("This is info message.")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, which ->
             
                }
                
                .show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center message in android dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954130/center-message-in-android-dialog-box)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the the title and the message you can use:

```
    <style name="MaterialAlertDialog__Center" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
        <item name="materialAlertDialogTitlePanelStyle">@style/Title.Panel.Center</item>
        <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/Message.Center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Title.Panel.Center" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Panel">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Message.Center" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>
```

with:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_Center)
                .setTitle("Message")
                ..
                .show()
```

[image]

Comment: it is working thank u, do you have any idea about center alignment button as well as custom font (title, subtitle & button)

Comment: @HariShankarS About the alignment I don't know a style solution. There aren't public method to do it. About the text, font, color of the button you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043299/2016562

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest way

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, com.google.android.material.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material3_MaterialAlertDialog_Centered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own layout and add it to your dialog

```
val inflater=LayoutInflater.from(requireContext())
//Getting the custom view
val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_LAYOUT,null)
//Obtaining the components
val title=view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_CUSTOM_TILE)
title.text="Message"
val button=view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_CUSTOM_BUTTON)
button.setOnCLickListener{
    //onClick
    }
val dialog=MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext()).setView(view).create()
dialog.show()
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I am looking style based solution (center alignment with custom font: material dialog title, subtitle & button).

Answer (score 0):

To center the title and message you only have to change this in your Theme

```
<item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog.Centered</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext(), com.google.android.material.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material3_MaterialAlertDialog_Centered))
                    .setTitle("Message")
                    .setMessage("This is info message.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, which ->
                 
                    }
                    
                    .show()
```